# How to exclude a child from contributing to parent layout's size in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When I use a Box, ConstraintLayout, Column or any other Layout types in Compose and add children to it, the parent always fits all the children within it. I don't want this behavior. I have a child composable with a height of 500dp, and I don't want the parent to fully fit this composable, but instead just clip the child. In Brief, when there are 5 children composables within a parent, I want the height of the parent to wrap 4 of the children and just clip the 5th child.

In the diagram below, the RED bar is an image and I want this to be clipped. The GREEN rectangle is what I want the parent layout to be, but instead I am getting the BLACK rectangle. The text in BLUE can grow or shrink, and I want the parent layout to wrap to this and change it's height based on this. How do I accomplish this?

[image]